# Is it possible to update IP2Location db?

Tags: node.js, ip2location

I want to update Ip2Location DB and add rows or change existing rows, is it possible? if so which package allows it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the node.js library, the IP2Location input file is a binary format. In this case, you could not modify it.